# How to modify django-celery web interface for periodic scheduling

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, celery, django-celery

I want to add few dropdownlists and input boxes for adding few other things using django-celery periodic scheduling web ui.

How can i do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own custom admin form by inheriting PeriodicTaskAdmin and overwriting methods / properties:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from djcelery.admin import PeriodicTaskAdmin as BasePeriodicTaskAdmin
from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask

class PeriodicTaskAdmin(BasePeriodicTaskAdmin):
    # Your code here


if PeriodicTask in admin.site._registry:
    admin.site.unregister(PeriodicTask)
admin.site.register(PeriodicTask, PeriodicTaskAdmin)
```

You can find [source code for PeriodicTaskAdmin on Github](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/admin.py#L296-L332).